# How to apply a string method to an svgTextElement in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to use the split method on all of the text elements in the data.
Here is my current code:

```
nodeEnter
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'text')
      .style('fill', function (d, i) {
        //the plan is to set colors of individual words based on certain conditions
        var color;
        var x = d.data.name.split(" ");
        return color;
      })
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.name;
      });
```

However, there is an error (in the image below) giving me a typeError, shown below.

[image: console error from above code]

Is this even possible to do? If this is the wrong approach (which I assume might be the case), what should I do? Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it with `textContent`, like `d.data.name.textContent.split(" ")`. Also check in the dev console which type `name` has, `console.log(d.data.name)` so you can see which methods are available or not from `name`.

Comment: hi @Telman, i tried using textContent but still received the same error. What do you think might be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `console.log(d.data.name)` ? Can you share the result ?